# how to set json data through for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am working on local weather widget for my website...
I have successfully displayed data using `OpenWeather Api`
Because i don't have sufficient experience in jquery/javascript, i am having difficulty in loading data for 10 days...
How can i do such thing, please some help....any kind of help or reference will be appreciated...

**Html & Script**

```
<div id="fatehjang"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function getWeather(coords, callback) {
                var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=33.568109&lon=72.642767&cnt=7';
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: url,
                    jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
                    data: { lat: coords[0], lon: coords[1] },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var teams;
                $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=33.568109&lon=72.642767&cnt=7", function (json) {
                    //do some thing with json  or assign global variable to incoming json.
                    teams = json;
                });
                $(window).load(function () {
                    for (var team in teams) {
                        var obj = teams[team];
                        (function (team) {
                            coords = [team.Lat, team.Long]
                            getWeather(coords, function (data) {
                                var html = [];
                                html.push('<h2 class="heading-md">')
                                html.push('Maximum Humidity: ', data.main.humidity, ', ');
                                html.push('</h2>')
                                $("#fatehjang").replaceWith(html.join('')).css("background-color", "white");
                            });
                        }(obj));
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>

**Html**
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: I see in your request you are using `cnt` parameter which I believe means `count` of days. Now you are getting the weather for 7 days, so the value of `cnt` is `7`. To take it for 10 days - change it in your url to `10`: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=33.568109&lon=72.642767&cnt=10 Does this answer your question - "i am having difficulty in loading data for 10 days.."? Or what the problem you have then? Describe it. And do it not only in the title but in the question's content. It more looks like you have one question in title and another in the body of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
                teams = json;
            });
            $(window).load(function () {
                for (var team in teams) {
```

to

```
                teams = json;
                for (var team in teams) {
```

The change above simply executes the code that "displays" the data as part of the "success" callback. As getJSON is asynchronous, the only safe place to do so is part of the success callback - I've seen people (I WORK with them) "fake" it with setTimeouts and such, and they think they've nailed it, until the server takes an extra second to respond - then all hell breaks loose :p

Comment: thanks for answer, i will surely accept it after testing +1 for effort

Comment: be warned, I haven't checked the validity of your code = however, I see what you were trying to achieve. - I've put a little explanation in the answer

Comment: `$("#fatehjang").replaceWith` suggests you are replacing the HTML in that element in every iteration of `teams` - perhaps you should use `$("#fatehjang").append` instead